# having some problems installing mod_perl on windows

Tags: windows, perl, apache, xampp, mod-perl

I want to run Perl on an Apache webserver in Xampp for Windows, but when i want to install Perl from the documentation here: http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/os/win32/install.html, there is 1 line i don't realy understand:

```
C:\modperl_src> perl Makefile.PL MP_AP_PREFIX=\Path\to\Apache2
```

What do they mean with the path to Apache and makefile.pl? Is it the path to the Apache folder or is it something else? I know this might look a very stupid question, but it is the first time i have to do this, so i want to do a good job.
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, It is the path to Apache 2. Makefile is used to "make" in *NIX.

Comment: I tried this but cmd gives me this in response:  Please repair your Module::CoreList at lib/Apache2/Build.pm line 49.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at lib/Apache2/Build.pm line 64.
Compilation failed in require at Makefile.PL line 37.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Makefile.PL line 37.

Comment: Could you try to install a Perl version prior to current? ( You are using ActivePerl, right? )

Comment: i am using this one: http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/P/PH/PHRED/mod_perl-2.0.7.tar.gz

Comment: Sorry for the slow response, read this:  http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=985243

Comment: thansks this really helped me out! :)